# Error in implementing a newcommand

Tags: macros

I am trying to implement a new command like that implemented by [Harvey Sheppard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/279318#279318) but I get the error

`! LaTeX Error: Command \@ already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, ...`

Can you tell me why I am getting this error?

Here is a snippet of the code that I have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Package Commands
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\picturespath}{pictures/}

% Title content
\newcommand{\@titleContent}[2]{
    \begin{minipage}{.75cm}
        \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
        \raisebox{2mm}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\picturespath #1}}
    \end{minipage}\hspace*{1mm}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-1.05cm}
            {\Large #2}
    \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

This is just a test of the code

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@` is command names are not allowed unless you're writing it as part of a `.cls` or `.sty`. If you're using `@` inside macros within your regular document, use

```
\makeatletter
% Your macros containing @ here
\makeatother
```

Reference: [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)